# How to find index of character in char array in C#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to find index of a character in char Array. I wrote below code, but I want
to use some `library function/ LINQ` to find the index rather than manually looping
through it. Is there any `smarter way/ concise way` I can achieve it.

Attempt:

```
    var index = -1;
    char[] x = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' , 'E'};

    for(int t = 0; t< x.Length; t++)
    {
        if (x[t] == 'E')
            index = t;
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Index is:  {index}");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For this example, you could use [Array.IndexOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2).

```
char[] x = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' };

Console.WriteLine($"Index is:  {Array.IndexOf(x, 'E')}");
```

Answer (score 1):

This is with LINQ :

```
char[] x = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E' };
var index = x.Select((c, i) => new {c, i}).SingleOrDefault(c => c.Equals('D')).i
```

with array class:

```
var index = Array.FindIndex(x, c=> c.Equals('E'));
```

Comment: Underneath the hood, it loops through the array. I think the OP wants an efficient algorithm to do this.

Comment: @ZackISSOIR: It's not like it's an indexed array.  Finding an item in an ordinary array is `O(n)`.

Comment: @ZackISSOIR: How would you find that without looping through the array.  As Robert Harvey points out, just about any useful solution will be an O(n) problem

Comment: You're right @RobertHarvey :)

Answer (score 0):

Use System.Linq `FindIndex`

```
char[] x = { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' , 'E'};
int index = x.ToList().FindIndex(c => c == 'E');
```

Comment: This requires that you enumerate the collection *twice.*

Comment: Well its a solution and since the array is not that big it should not be a problem :) you think about performance issue when you have an array that are over at least 1000 :)